# Material-ui avoid FOIT when loading Roboto font

Tags: fonts, material-ui, next.js

I am working with material-ui@next(v1) and trying to avoid FOIT when loading Roboto font. I am trying to implement [class replacing strategy](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-events.html).

Problem? For this, to work I would have to add a custom class to every material element **in my app**.

Another solution is to set `fontFamily: ''` in createMuiTheme and then add class with `font-family: roboto` to body once font is loaded.
But that just seems wrong and it doesn't even set font-family correctly for all material typography elements.

What other options do I have? Perhaps re-creating entire MuiTheme(with different typography) once font is loaded? But that means re-rendering entire app if I understand correctly.

Oh and I am using it [with next.js](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/v1-beta/examples/nextjs)